# Use my own router if ISP supplid does not support bridge

Tags: networking, router, bridge-router

I have a Technicolor TC7200 I am getting sick of. I'd like to get my own router, slap OpenWRT on it and control my LAN myself. Also, I'd like to have more control over my wireless.

The Technicolor modem has a menu entry that lets me switch from “router mode” to “bridged mode”, it does not have any effect, though. Is is possible to use a second router behind the ISP supplied modem when the modem will always use DHCP and has no bridged mode?

Comment: Sure. I think the Technicolor can configure one device to have your public IP. This is like a DMZ. You can then use your network as desired...

Comment: Normally all that's required is to connect the router to the modem.

Comment: I read [in a German forum](http://www.unitymediakabelbwforum.de/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=26812&start=90#p293999) that this will not bring the IPv6 address to my machines correctly, yielding in a three NATs and the DS-Lite tunnel on the way. Only the mid-2014 version of OpenWrt seems to support this IPv6 thing correctly.

Comment: If you can't turn off DHCP, and make that device in bridged mode then you'll have an issue with another device doing DHCP.. Maybe you can change your ISP supplied modem. Or maybe you're not setting it correctly.

Comment: I cannot change the ISP supplied modem. The *bridged mode* option is disabled as well. So the only two options are probably using another router as a plain access point (nothing gained) or using the router as the only DCHP client of the ISP supplied modem (might break IPv6 I heard). The ISP supplied modem is more locked down than an iPhone!

Comment: @queueoverflow I suppose you could set all your devices(aside from the locked down isp one), to have a static ip, thus ignore the IPs sent out by your isp device. I suppose maybe you could choose not to do NAT on the ddwrt one, or to do it. (some don't mind double NAT, but you could turn NAT off on your ddwrt but still have it as a router). I suppose you'd get the benefits of ddwrt, more control.